# Error on add the Media Router cast button

Tags: android, google-cast, android-appcompat, android-actionbaractivity

I try to implement a cast function to my app using the [CastCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android).
When it tries to add the Media Router Cast Button to the ActionBar I get this error:

```
10-03 19:33:20.098  11781-11781/de.resper.e2cast W/MenuItemCompat﹕ getActionProvider: item does not implement SupportMenuItem; returning null
10-03 19:33:20.098  11781-11781/de.resper.e2cast W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41ebde18)
10-03 19:33:20.098  11781-11781/de.resper.e2cast E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.resper.e2cast, PID: 11781
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.sample.castcompanionlibrary.cast.BaseCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(BaseCastManager.java:355)
at de.resper.e2cast.ChannelCastActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(ChannelCastActivity.java:655)
```

the position in the CahnnelCastActivity is:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    mCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item); <--- ERROR
    return true;
}
```

i have included:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and extended with:

```
public class ChannelCastActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

and in the BaseCastManager is the error line:

```
public MenuItem addMediaRouterButton(Menu menu, int menuResourceId) {
    MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(menuResourceId);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
    mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector); <--- ERROR
    if (null != getMediaRouteDialogFactory()) {
        mediaRouteActionProvider.setDialogFactory(getMediaRouteDialogFactory());
    }
    return mediaRouteMenuItem;
}
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ChannelCastActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_channel_cast"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.resper.e2cast.MainActivity" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </activity>
```

Comment: Can you post your `R.menu.main`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your menu item has an action view of [android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteActionProvider.html) and NOT [android.app.MediaRouteActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/MediaRouteActionProvider.html) - Chromecast requires the support-v7 versions.

Comment: Thx. Checked all but not the menu xml. Thy for help, will accept the answer in 5 min.